# compaction history out of order

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using nodetool to view compaction history, and get the attached image [image]

As you can see the times are completely out of order, and range from Match 17th (1489786637207) to 21st (1490122248602)

We are using Cassandra 3.0.8, uploading the sstables with the [bulk loader](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated), and are using TimeWindowCompactionStrategy compaction.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compaction history table isn't ordered:

```
CREATE TABLE system.compaction_history (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  bytes_in bigint,
  bytes_out bigint,
  columnfamily_name text,
  compacted_at timestamp,
  keyspace_name text,
  rows_merged map<int, bigint>
)
```

It just has a `default_time_to_live = 604800` which expires data after 1 week. Nodetool is really just printing this table.

edit:
So actually nodetool is supposed sort the result from jmx on client side. [CompactionHistoryHolder](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/nodetool/stats/CompactionHistoryHolder.java#L118) will sort it, and the compareTo checks the [compactedAt](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/nodetool/stats/CompactionHistoryHolder.java#L71) field. So it not being sorted by the time of the compaction is probably a bug. I would recommend opening a [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA) with more details.

Comment: Thanks! That's interesting. Any way to get the ordered history from nodetool (that's what I would imagine most people want)

Comment: Try this as a work around


nodetool compactionhistory |awk '{timestamp = strftime("%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y",$4 /1000);in_m=$5/1024/1024;out_m=$6/1024/1024;printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%dM\t%dM\n",$4,timestamp,$2,$3,in_m,out_m)}' |sort -n